# Flutter OpenContainer rebuild when state change?

Tags: flutter, animation

Hi iam using OpenContainer to show on the open a statefull widget but when call setstate the widget is not re-build. it this suppose to happens?

Example code:

```
 class StatefulWidgetExample extends StatefulWidget {
  StatefulWidgetExample({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _StatefulWidgetExampleState createState() => _StatefulWidgetExampleState();
}

class _StatefulWidgetExampleState extends State<StatefulWidgetExample> {
  String _someText = 'some text';

  void _changeText() {
    setState(() {
      _someText = _someText + ' some other text ';
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Test Widget')),
      body: OpenContainer(
        closedBuilder: (context, openContainer) {
          return Center(child: Text('Open The Conatiner'));
        },
        openBuilder: (context, closeContainer) {
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Open Container')),
                  body: Column(
                    children:[
                      Text('My Text:  $_someText'),
                      FlatButton(
                        child:Text('Change Text'),
                        onPress:_changeText,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );}
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the code above a function is called to change the text of a Text Widget inside the openbuilder of the openContainer, but this is not working, if you print on the console you observe that hte function is called but the ui is not rebuilded.

Comment: Could you please post some of your relevant code?

Comment: Can you please add the code

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the content of the openBuilder with a StatefulBuilder like so:

```
openBuilder: (BuildContext context, closeContainer) {
    return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
        return Content();
    }
}
```